# Power apps drop down

Tags: powerapps

In power apps I have created a drop down list called series and another called models. How do I get the drop down in Models to reference an item in the Series drop down? For example, If the series has car, truck, van how to i get the models list to auto populate when car is chosen.

Answer (score 3):

To do that you will need to set up some collections to be used in your dropdown , and use condition to make the second dropdown change the values.

Example:

You can add a new button or use the visibility property of the screen and set these collections :

Collect(MyLetters, "A","B","C"); Collect(MyNumbers, "1","2","3");Collect(Roman,"i","ii","iii"); Collect(Dots,"a","aa","aaa")

1- In your DropDown1 , you can set items to MyLetters

2- In DropDown2 set items to the condition like this : If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value= "A",MyNumbers, If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value= "B", Roman, If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value= "C", Dots)))

Thanks,

Eman

Comment: I couldn't get this to work can you be a little more detailed if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution without using Collections.

**Step-1** Create two Dropdowns and rename them **ddProductCat** and **ddProductSubCat** respectively.

**Step-2** Paste this line on the **Item** property of **ddProductCat**.

```
["Car", "Truck", "Van"]
```

**Step-3** Paste below code on the **Item** Property of **ddProductSubCat**

```
If( ddProductCat.SelectedText.Value="Car",["BMW","Volvo", "Audi"],
    If(ddProductCat.SelectedText.Value="Van", ["Mersides","Volvo", "Toyota"],
        If(ddProductCat.SelectedText.Value="Truck", ["Toyota", "Tata"]
        )
    )
)
```

This solution is not recommended if you have bulk data or you may need to add/modify data in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You need to define your data a bit more in the OP.

**Yet another option is:**

1. OnVisible of the screen

```
    Concurrent(
        ClearCollect(colListOfModels, YourModelDataSource),
        ClearCollect(colListOfSeries, YourSeriesDataSource)
    )
```

2. **dd**Series Items Property

   `colListOfSeries`
3. **dd**Models Items Property

   `Filter(colListOfModels, series = ddSeries.Selected.Value)`

This assumes two DataSources, two Collections and a Series identifier in the Models Collection.

Answer (score 0):

add code on the Model dropdown > Items Properties
Filter(SeriesModelTable,SeriesColumn=DropdownSeries.Selected.SeriesColumn)